# firefox background position percentage not working

Tags: html, css, firefox

I merged a set of images into a large one to save HTTP requests and used `background-position` in percentage to adjust which image to use. Percentage is used rather than pixel since the width of images is controlled by the parent element.

The merged image is like:

[image]

As about the rendered result, please refer to the first five images in http://zhujianer.com/ .

It works fine on Chrome.
[image]
From Console, we can see the CSS selector.
[image]

But it unexpectedly uses the same image in Firefox. (Tested on FF 17.0.1 on Mac)
[image]
From Firebug, the selector is there, but the attribute `background-position-x: -200%;` is gone. And even if I add it, FF will automatically removes it. So it seems that this is regarded as illegal to FF.

[image]

Full CSS code is (using SCSS):

```
.process {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .image-block {
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        background-size: 500%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 5%;
        background-image: url('../img/process.png');

        &:hover {
            background-position-y: 100%;
        };
    }

    &#process-idea .image-block {
        background-position-x: 0;
    }

    &#process-design .image-block {
        background-position-x: -100%;
    }

    &#process-code .image-block {
        background-position-x: -200%;
    }

    &#process-launch .image-block {
        background-position-x: -300%;
    }

    &#process-monitor .image-block {
        background-position-x: -400%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FF doesn't know about `background-position-x`, he knows only about background-position. So you can write this like:

```
#process-section #process-idea.process .image-block {
    background-position: -200% 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed -  Apparently Firefox needs both x & y at the same time so background-position-x was ignored